# Get Facebook friends who liked an external page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

How can we display the friends who liked an external page like those displayed in like box.

[Like box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages) can be only used for facebook pages. Can anyone please help.

Can I do this without using FQL?

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible anymore since Graph API v2.0. All friends permissions have been removed, see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions